# Is there a b5paper japanese style in latex?

Tags: layout, latex, document

My thesis is written in b5j documentclass style.

```
\documentclass[b5j,twoside,12pt]{report}
```

I have a paper that is appended at the end. However this is written in b5paper style as an article.

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper,twoside]{article}
```

How do I get the paper to follow the japanese style? Havent found any b5paperj options in the geometry package.. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to build the paper that must be appended separately and input it in your document using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf). This way you don't have to control both styles and the package provides enough flexibility to make it look like you want to.